# Python analog of condition? true : false

Tags: python

Is there python function in standard library like

```
def cond(condition, true, false):
  if condition:
    return true
  return false

x = 20
s = cond(x > 10, "x greater than 10", "x less or equals 10")
```

Comment: Related question [Python Ternary Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator).

Comment: Such a function shouldn't exist, since it will evaluate both true and false arguments in all cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python has a ternary operation but it is done as an "if expression" instead of with question mark and colon.

```
s = "x greater than 10" if x > 10 else "x less or equals 10"
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has a ternary-like operator (it's actually called a *conditional expression*), which reads like this:

```
s = "x greater than 10" if x > 10 else "x less or equals 10"
```